# Xamarin SQLite variable fieldlist

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

I have a VS2017 Xamarin forms crossplattform project and I would like to have a 'select * from table1' but I dont know which fields are in '*'.

All samples that I found need to know the fieldlist through a defined class.
I can do a

```
Object o = db.Query<Object>("SELECT * FROM table1");
```

It compiles and runs but the only information I get from o is that it is a systemobject. 
Is there a chance that I get something that i can iterate and see all the fieldnames und values of the SQL result?

Comment: Please format your message. It is very hard to read.

Comment: `table1` should be the name of the class you used to create the table, so why can't you just instantiate a new `table1` object? `IEnumerable<table1> result = db.Query<table1>("SELECT * FROM [table1]");`

Comment: I don't know the structure of the table, I'm not the creator i just want to show the user a list of the fieldnames + values, without knowing the structure nor having a clas definition.